# key word extraction with TF_IDF

Tags: python, tfidfvectorizer

I want to write a function to get one element of my list and tell  me 10 key words of it using TF-IDF.I have seen codes but I could not implement it. each element of my list is a long sentence.
I have written these two functions and I do not know how to do what I said above.

```
def fit(train_data):
    cleaned_lst=[]
    for element in train_data:
        #removing customized stop words
        cleaned = remove(element)
        cleaned_lst.append(cleaned)
    for sentence in cleaned_lst:
        vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer = word_tokenize)
        fitted_data = vectorizer.fit([sentence])
    return fitted_data


def transfom(test_data):
    transformed_data = fit(train_data).transform([element for element in test_data])
    return transformed_data
```